# Tooltip for "Application" page

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page, tooltips

As far as I see only the "Application" item has tooltip in [Settings section of profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/):

> [image: Applications]

Should it be removed? Or add tooltips for the rest items?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be the only list item with a `title` attribute in the HTML.  If you add a `title` attribute to any of the other list items, it will also display them:

[image]

I would say one of the following:

- Rename the list item to be "Authorized Applications" and remove the title
- Remove the title all together
- Add a title to the rest of the items to be consistent